# Didn't show data from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I would like to show all data from database.

[image]

But it doesn't work. 
My Web.config file

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="EFDbContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=NewsList;Integrated Security=True"/>
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using NewsList.Domain.Abstract;
using NewsList.Domain.Entities;


namespace NewsList.WebUI1.Controllers
{
public class NewsController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /News/
    private INewsRepository repository;
    public NewsController(INewsRepository newsRepository)
    {
     this.repository = newsRepository;
    }

    public ViewResult List()
    {
        return View(repository.NewsList);
    }


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
}
```

Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NewsList.Domain.Entities
{
public class News
{
    public int NewsID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
}
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<NewsList.Domain.Entities.News>

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "News";
 }

@foreach (var p in Model)
{
<div class="item">
    <h3>@p.Title</h3>
    @p.Description
    <h4>@p.Text</h4>
</div>
}
```

And now I haven't got any exeptions. Only clear while browser page.

Comment: Please add the code of the `NewsRepostitory` (or anything implementing `INewsRepository`). Do you have any data in the database?
Also, you could put a breakpoint at `return View(repository.NewsList);` to see if `NewsList` returns any data.

Comment: Any change in functionality if you call `View(repositor.NewsList.ToList());`?

Comment: [Connections](http://snag.gy/DmBuh.jpg) here you can see all connections.Data in database [data](http://snag.gy/hWn1f.jpg)

Comment: Erik Philips, no, nothing changes.

Comment: It's all of wrong datatypes in model. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as an example:

```
public class NewsRepository  : INewsRepository 
{
    private YourDbContext db = null;

    public List<NewsList> NewsList
    {
        return this.db.NewsList.ToList();
    }

    public NewsRepository()
    {
        this.db = new NewsRepository();
    }
}

public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<NewsList> NewsList {get; set;}
}
```